# GLESDebugDraw only for iOS usage?

Tags: c++, iphone, box2d, cocos2d-x

I'm using some examples from this book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Cocos2d-x-Example-Beginners-Guide-Engelbert-ebook/dp/B00CITNP8A/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1393328148&sr=8-1&keywords=cocos2d-x](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CITNP8A)

and in them he uses Box2D with GLESDebugDraw.  When I tried compiling for Win32 it complained that it couldn't find GLES-Render.h. I did some digging and found it in:
C:\Box2D_v2.3.0\Contributions\Platforms\iPhone\Classes

That leads me to believe that this is for iOS usage only.  Is it?

I tried including the *Render.h file from there but it then complained about more header files not found... which seemed even more iOS specific.

Thanks for any info!

Comment: Hi, you can also try this [implementation](https://github.com/vinova/B2DebugDraw). Works great. Simply add the files to your project and call addChild(B2DebugDrawLayer::create(mWorld, DEBUG_PTM_RATIO));.